# Redirect subdomain to parameter without wildcard SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, parameters, subdomain, wildcard

I'm trying to do which might be not possible at all.
Let's say I own mydomain.com and have standard (no wildcard) RapidSSL certificate which works for **www.mydomain.com** and **mydomain.com**.

I'd like to redirect (.htaccess) subdomain.mydomain.com to **mydomain.com/?param=subdomain**.

I already managed to redirect it to **subdomain.mydomain.com/?param=subdomain**  but the problem is that on every redirection I get browser warning concerning my certificate which doesn't cover any subdomain.

Is it possible to redirect it without the warning? I need subdomain only for pretty passing the parameter and I don't need it after redirection.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to capture the subdomain in the URL as shown in the 2nd RewriteCond and then use it as the parameter value:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
   Options +FollowSymLinks 
   Options +Indexes 
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteBase / 
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.mydomain.com$ [NC] 
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).mydomain.com [NC] 
   RewriteRule (.*)?param=%2/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

This is a link to the above solution... http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/server/apache/mod-rewrite/subdomains.html

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

> ...  (no wildcard) RapidSSL certificate which works for www.example.com and example.com .... like to redirect (.htaccess) subdomain.example.com to example.com/?param=subdomain

This is not possible, at least not without warnings about invalid certificates.

The redirection is done within HTTP. But with HTTPS the HTTP layer is embedded inside a SSL layer so that you first have to successfully establish the SSL connection before you can redirect. But to successfully establish the SSL connection you have to have a valid certificate for subdomain.example.com, which you don't have.